# ES6 Generator Function To Retrieve SMART FHIR References to Origin

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hl7-fhir

I'm experimenting with this application using the FHIR.js API and would like to create an iterator for any CarePlans that reference multiple goals; if a person clicks on an arrow the user can cycle through the goals by a click action event. I'm using a generator function and it seems to work, but I'm receiving an undefined value on the first call of my `.next` method. Can anyone care to explain why this provides the first yield using this function?

```
  refs = ["#goal-1", "#goal-2", "#goal-3", "#goal-4", "#goal-5"];
  //Goal Id tags referenced for CarePlan

  function* referenceGetter(refs, resource) {
    var i=0;
    var x;
    while (true){
       window.FHIR.oauth2.ready(smart=>{
          smart.api.search({type: resource, query:{_id: refs[i]}})
                        .done(e=>{x = 
                              e.data.entry[0].resource;i++;
                         })
                        .fail(err=>{x= err;i++;});
        });
        //Yield the returned bundles here;
        yield x;
    }
  }
```

When I run:

```
getRefs = referenceGetter(refs, "Goal");
getRefs.next()
```

The **first** return object is

```
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

But then it retrieves the first reference to the first id if I call it again. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thank You

Consider:

I'm utilizing the stu3-ver smart-on-fhir api.

Comment: Don't use generators. Use `async`/`await`. Hint: both will work only when `x` is a promise -  which it [clearly isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) in your code.

Comment: Something like this?

async function referGetter(refs, resource){
 var start = Date.now();
 await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  FHIR.oauth2.ready(smart=>
   smart.api.search({type: resource, id: refs[index]})
   .done(result=>{resolve(result.data.entry[0].resource);++index})
   .fail(err=>{reject(err);++index})
  )
    }).then(success=>console.log(success)).catch(err=>console.error(err));
 var end = Date.now();
 console.log("Took approximately", new Date(end-start).getMilliseconds());
}

index being a global variable

Comment: How would the generator work though? I feel like the generator is little less taxing with the syntax.

Comment: No, more like `async function referGetter(refs, resource){ var start = Date.now(); var smart = await new Promise(resolve => FHIR.oauth2.ready(resolve)); try { var result = await smart.api.search({type: resource, id: refs[index]}); console.log(result.data.entry[0].resource); } catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { ++i‌​ndex; } var end = Date.now(); console.log("Took approximately", new Date(end-start).getMilliseconds()); }`.

Comment: No, that's the whole point - `async`/`await` is less taxing with the syntax, it just works. No need to explicitly advance the generator asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you, this approach is more concrete